# Как добавить сумму полей только один раз при клике?

Tags: javascript, html

При клике на выходной день в календаре к сумме и значению под инпутом должно прибавляться число, которое находится в .it-price-students-weekend. Подскажите как сделать так, что-бы оно прибавлялось только один раз? и если нажали не на выходной день то это прибавлении убирается? Сейчас я когда кликаю на выходной день то числа прибавляються при каждом клике или вводе значения в инпут. Уже всю голову себе сломал. Спасибо

```js
const calendar = document.querySelector(".calendar__main");
if (calendar) {
  const input = document.querySelector("#date");
  const calHeader = document.querySelector(".calendar__header");
  const calHeaderTitle = document.querySelector(".calendar__header span");
  const calDays = document.querySelector(".calendar__days");
  const days = ["Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб", "Вс"];
  const months = [
    "Январь",
    "Февраль",
    "Март",
    "Апрель",
    "Май",
    "Июнь",
    "Июль",
    "Август",
    "Сентябрь",
    "Октябрь",
    "Ноябрь",
    "Декабрь"
  ];

  let oneDay = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
  let todayTimestamp =
    Date.now() -
    (Date.now() % oneDay) +
    new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 1000 * 60;

  let selectedDay = todayTimestamp;
  // console.log(selectedDay); // Str in millisec

  // Get num of days in month
  // month param 0-11
  const getNumberOfDays = (year, month) => {
    return 40 - new Date(year, month, 40).getDate();
  };
  // getNumberOfDays(2023, 1);

  // Calc day details
  const getDayDetails = (args) => {
    let date = args.index - args.firstDay;
    let day = args.index % 7;
    // console.log(day)
    let prevMonth = args.month - 1;
    let prevYear = args.year;
    if (prevMonth < 0) {
      prevMonth = 11;
      prevYear--;
    }
    let prevMonthNumberOfDays = getNumberOfDays(prevYear, prevMonth);

    let _date =
      (date < 0 ? prevMonthNumberOfDays + date : date % args.numberOfDays) + 1;
    // console.log(_date)
    let month = date < 0 ? -1 : date >= args.numberOfDays ? 1 : 0;
    let timestamp = new Date(args.year, args.month, _date).getTime();
    // console.log(timestamp)
    return {
      date: _date,
      day,
      month,
      timestamp,
      dayString: days[day]
    };
  };

  // [{}] each {} with details for each day of month
  const getMonthDetails = (year, month) => {
    let firstDay = new Date(year, month).getDay();
    let numberOfDays = getNumberOfDays(year, month);
    let monthArray = [];
    let rows = 5;
    let currentDay = null;
    let index = 0;
    let cols = 7;

    for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        currentDay = getDayDetails({
          index,
          numberOfDays,
          firstDay,
          year,
          month
        });
        monthArray.push(currentDay);
        index++;
      }
    }
    return monthArray;
  };
  // getMonthDetails(2023, 3)

  // Variables that get updated with "state" changes
  let date = new Date();
  let year = date.getFullYear();
  let month = date.getMonth();
  let monthDetails = getMonthDetails(year, month);

  const isCurrentDay = (day, cell) => {
    if (day.timestamp === todayTimestamp) {
      cell.classList.add("active");
      cell.classList.add("isCurrent");
    }
  };

  // Checks if day is one selected
  const isSelectedDay = (day, cell) => {
    if (day.timestamp === selectedDay) {
      cell.classList.add("active");
      cell.classList.add("isSelected");
    }
  };

  // Get month str
  const getMonthStr = (month) =>
    months[Math.max(Math.min(11, month), 0)] || "Month";
  // console.log(getMonthStr(month))

  // Set year using arrows
  const setHeaderNav = (offset) => {
    month = month + offset;
    if (month === -1) {
      month = 11;
      year--;
    } else if (month === 12) {
      month = 0;
      year++;
    }
    monthDetails = getMonthDetails(year, month);
    // console.log(getMonthDetails(year, month))
    return {
      year,
      month,
      monthDetails
    };
  };

  // Set dynamic calendar header
  const setHeader = (year, month) => {
    calHeaderTitle.innerHTML = getMonthStr(month) + " " + year;
  };

  // Set calendar header
  setHeader(year, month);

  // 1677139200000 => "2023-02-23"
  const getDateStringFromTimestamp = (timestamp) => {
    let dateObject = new Date(timestamp);
    let month = dateObject.getMonth();
    let date = dateObject.getDate();
    // return (
    //   dateObject.getFullYear() +
    //   "-" +
    //   (month < 10 ? "0" + month : month) +
    //   "-" +
    //   (date < 10 ? "0" + date : date)
    // );
    return `${getMonthStr(month)} ${date}, ${dateObject.getFullYear()}`;
  };

  const setDateToInput = (timestamp) => {
    let dateString = getDateStringFromTimestamp(timestamp);
    input.value = dateString;
  };
  setDateToInput(todayTimestamp);

  // Add days row to calendar
  for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    let div = document.createElement("div"),
      span = document.createElement("span");

    div.classList.add("cell_wrapper");
    // div.classList.add("cal_days");
    span.classList.add("cell_item");

    span.innerText = days[i].slice(0, 2);

    div.appendChild(span);
    calDays.appendChild(div);
  }

  // Add dates to calendar
  const setCalBody = (monthDetails) => {
    // Add dates to calendar
    for (let i = 0; i < monthDetails.length; i++) {
      let div = document.createElement("div"),
        span = document.createElement("span");

      div.classList.add("cell_wrapper");
      div.classList.add("cal_date");
      div.classList.add("input-calc");
      monthDetails[i].month === 0 && div.classList.add("current");
      monthDetails[i].month === 0 && isCurrentDay(monthDetails[i], div);
      span.classList.add("cell_item");
      var fifth_1 = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".calendar__main .cell_wrapper.cal_date:nth-child(5)"
      );
      fifth_1.forEach((five) => {
        five.classList.add("fifth-day");
      });
      var fifth_2 = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".calendar__main .cell_wrapper.cal_date:nth-child(12)"
      );
      fifth_2.forEach((five) => {
        five.classList.add("fifth-day");
      });
      var fifth_3 = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".calendar__main .cell_wrapper.cal_date:nth-child(19)"
      );
      fifth_3.forEach((five) => {
        five.classList.add("fifth-day");
      });
      var fifth_4 = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".calendar__main .cell_wrapper.cal_date:nth-child(26)"
      );
      fifth_4.forEach((five) => {
        five.classList.add("fifth-day");
      });
      var fifth_5 = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".calendar__main .cell_wrapper.cal_date:nth-child(33)"
      );
      fifth_5.forEach((five) => {
        five.classList.add("fifth-day");
      });

      var sixth_1 = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".calendar__main .cell_wrapper.cal_date:nth-child(6)"
      );
      sixth_1.forEach((six) => {
        six.classList.add("weekend");
      });
      var sixth_2 = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".calendar__main .cell_wrapper.cal_date:nth-child(13)"
      );
      sixth_2.forEach((six) => {
        six.classList.add("weekend");
      });
      var sixth_3 = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".calendar__main .cell_wrapper.cal_date:nth-child(20)"
      );
      sixth_3.forEach((six) => {
        six.classList.add("weekend");
      });
      var sixth_4 = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".calendar__main .cell_wrapper.cal_date:nth-child(27)"
      );
      sixth_4.forEach((six) => {
        six.classList.add("weekend");
      });
      var sixth_5 = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".calendar__main .cell_wrapper.cal_date:nth-child(34)"
      );
      sixth_5.forEach((six) => {
        six.classList.add("weekend");
      });

      var seventh = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".calendar__main .cell_wrapper.cal_date:nth-child(7n)"
      );
      seventh.forEach((seven) => {
        seven.classList.add("weekend");
      });

      span.innerText = monthDetails[i].date;

      div.appendChild(span);
      calendar.appendChild(div);
    }
  };

  setCalBody(monthDetails);

  const updateCalendar = (btn) => {
    let newCal, offset;
    if (btn.classList.contains("calendar__btn-prev")) {
      // let { year, month, monthDetails } = setHeaderNav(-1);
      offset = -1;
    } else if (btn.classList.contains("calendar__btn-next")) {
      // let { year, month, monthDetails } = setHeaderNav(1);
      offset = 1;
    }
    newCal = setHeaderNav(offset);
    // console.log(monthDetails)
    setHeader(newCal.year, newCal.month);
    calendar.innerHTML = "";
    setCalBody(newCal.monthDetails);
  };

  // Only one calendar date is selected
  const selectOnClick = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll(".cell_wrapper").forEach((cell) => {
      cell.classList.contains("isSelected") && cell.classList.remove("active");

      if (
        cell.classList.contains("isCurrent") &&
        !cell.classList.contains("active")
      ) {
        cell.querySelector("span").classList.add("inactive_indicator");
      }
    });
  };

  const updateInput = () => {
    let currentDay = document.querySelector(".isCurrent");

    // Update input based on clicked cell
    document.querySelectorAll(".cell_wrapper").forEach((cell) => {
      if (cell.classList.contains("current")) {
        cell.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          let cell_date = e.target.textContent;

          currentDay !== null && currentDay.classList.remove("active");

          for (let i = 0; i < monthDetails.length; i++) {
            if (monthDetails[i].month === 0) {
              if (monthDetails[i].date.toString() === cell_date) {
                selectedDay = monthDetails[i].timestamp;
                setDateToInput(selectedDay);
                selectOnClick();

                isSelectedDay(monthDetails[i], cell);

                cell
                  .querySelector("span")
                  .classList.contains("inactive_indicator") &&
                  cell
                    .querySelector("span")
                    .classList.remove("inactive_indicator");
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };

  updateInput();

  // Set header nav actions
  document.querySelectorAll(".calendar-btn").forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      updateCalendar(btn);
      updateInput();
    });
  });

  input.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(".calendar__content").classList.toggle("hidden");
    document.querySelector(".calendar__input").classList.toggle("showCal");
    document.querySelector("#date").classList.toggle("onFocus");
  });
}

//калькулятор
const inputNumberStudents = document.querySelector("#number");

const numberStudentsPrice = document.querySelector(".it-price-students-small"); //цена за 1 школьника < 17
const numberStudentsPrice_2 = document.querySelector(
  ".it-price-students-medium"
); //цена за 1 школьника > 17 < 28
const numberStudentsPrice_3 = document.querySelector(".it-price-students-big"); //цена за 1 школьника > 30 < 50
const numberStudentsPriceWeekend = document.querySelector(
  ".it-price-students-weekend"
); //цена за 1 школьника выходные

const totalPrice = document.querySelector(".form-popup__total-new-price");
const inputTotals = document.querySelectorAll('.input-calc'); //инпуты

const basePrice = 0;

function calculater() {
  let totalPriceElement = basePrice;

  inputNumberStudents.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
    if (inputNumberStudents.value <= 17) {
      numberStudentsPrice.classList.add("_active");
      numberStudentsPrice_3.classList.remove("_active");
      numberStudentsPrice_2.classList.remove("_active");
    } else if (
      inputNumberStudents.value >= 19 &&
      inputNumberStudents.value <= 28
    ) {
      numberStudentsPrice.classList.remove("_active");
      numberStudentsPrice_2.classList.add("_active");
      numberStudentsPrice_3.classList.remove("_active");
    } else if (
      inputNumberStudents.value >= 30 &&
      inputNumberStudents.value <= 50
    ) {
      numberStudentsPrice_3.classList.add("_active");
      numberStudentsPrice.classList.remove("_active");
      numberStudentsPrice_2.classList.remove("_active");
    }
  });
  
  if (numberStudentsPrice.classList.contains("_active")) {
        totalPriceElement = (totalPriceElement) + inputNumberStudents.value * numberStudentsPrice.innerHTML;
        if (document.documentElement.classList.contains("_active-weekend")) {
            numberStudentsPrice.innerHTML = +numberStudentsPrice.innerHTML + +numberStudentsPriceWeekend.innerHTML;
            console.log(numberStudentsPrice.innerHTML)
        }
    }
    if (numberStudentsPrice_2.classList.contains("_active")) {
        totalPriceElement = (totalPriceElement) + inputNumberStudents.value * numberStudentsPrice_2.innerHTML;
        totalPriceElement_2 = totalPriceElement_2 + (inputNumberStudents.value * numberStudentsPrice_2.innerHTML);
    }
    if (numberStudentsPrice_3.classList.contains("_active")) {
        totalPriceElement = (totalPriceElement) + inputNumberStudents.value * numberStudentsPrice_3.innerHTML;
        totalPriceElement_2 = totalPriceElement_2 + (inputNumberStudents.value * numberStudentsPrice_3.innerHTML);
    }

  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("ru");
  totalPrice.innerText = formatter.format(totalPriceElement);
}

calculater();

//календарь
document.querySelectorAll(".cell_wrapper").forEach((cell) => {
  if (cell) {
    cell.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      const calendarItemFifth = document.querySelector(
        ".cell_wrapper.cal_date.current.fifth-day.active"
      );
      if (calendarItemFifth) {
        document.documentElement.classList.add("_active-wek-fifth");
      } else {
        document.documentElement.classList.remove("_active-wek-fifth");
      }
      const calendarItemsSixth = document.querySelector(
        ".cell_wrapper.cal_date.current.weekend.active"
      );
      if (calendarItemsSixth) {
        document.documentElement.classList.add("_active-weekend");
      } else {
        document.documentElement.classList.remove("_active-weekend");
      }
      calculater();
    });
  }
});

inputTotals.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('input', function () {
        calculater();
    });
});
```

```css
.calendar{
  position: relative;
}
.calendar__input {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
.calendar__input input {
  cursor: pointer;
   width: 100%;
}
.calendar__input input._form-focus {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
.calendar__input.showCal input {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.calendar__input.showCal::before {
  color: green;
}
.calendar__input::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #afafaf;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}
.calendar__content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 40;
  right: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  top: 99%;
  width: auto;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.calendar__header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0px 0px 24px 0px;
}
.calendar__header span {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.calendar__btn-prev {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px 27px 0px 0px;
}
.calendar__btn-prev::before {
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.calendar__btn-prev:hover::before {
  color: green;
}
.calendar__btn-next {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.calendar__btn-next::before {
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.calendar__btn-next:hover::before {
  color: green;
}
.calendar__days {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 35px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  margin: 0px 0px 16px 0px;
}
.calendar__main {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 35px;
  row-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, min(32px));
}

.cal_date .cell_item {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 32px;
  min-height: 32px;
}

.cell_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.cell_wrapper .cell_item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 32px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.5);
}
.cell_wrapper.active .cell_item {
  background: #efa021;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.current .cell_item {
  color: #111111;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.calculator{
  margin:20px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.it-price-students-small._active {
    display: block;
}
.it-price-students-medium._active {
    display: block;
}
.it-price-students-big._active {
    display: block;
}
.it-price-students-small {
    display: none;
}
.it-price-students-medium {
    display: none;
}
.it-price-students-big {
    display: none;
}
.it-price-students-weekend {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="tabs-transmit-readings__calendar calendar">
  <div class="calendar__input  _icon-calendar">
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="date" class="onFocus" readonly>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar__content hidden">
    <div class="calendar__header">
      <span></span>
      <button class="calendar__btn-prev calendar-btn _icon-arrow-slider"></button>
      <button class="calendar__btn-next calendar-btn _icon-arrow-slider"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar__wrapper">
      <div class="calendar__days"></div>
      <div class="calendar__main"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="calculator">
<input data-required="" id="number" autocomplete="off" type="text" min="0" max="50" name="text" value="1" placeholder="1" class="input input-calc" data-placeholder="1">
<span class="it-price-students-small _active">1000</span>
  <span class="it-price-students-medium">2000</span>
  <span class="it-price-students-big">3000</span>
<span class="it-price-students-weekend">100</span>

<div class="form-popup__total-new-price">0</div>
    </div>
</html>
```